# Merge array values and array_walk_recursive

Tags: php, array-merge, array-walk

The title is terrible, but unfortunately I can't think of anything better to describe my situation.

Suppose the following code, and I'll then explain what I want.

```
$invalid_id = array('100', '110', '120');
$invalid_status = array('200', '210');
$already_exported = array('400', '450');

$tmp = array(
    'There is no order with that ID' => $invalid_id,
    'The order has an invalis status' => $invalid_status,
    'The order was previously exported' => $already_exported,
);

echo '<div><p>' . sprintf('No orders were exported (%s).', implode(', ', array_merge($invalid_id, $invalid_status, $already_exported))) . '</p></div>';
```

So the code above produces an output like this: `<div><p>No orders were exported (100, 110, 120, 200, 210, 400, 450).</p></div>`

The problem is I want to add a reason for why each order id was rejected. So I used the `$tmp` array were the keys are the reasons why each array's values (order ids) were rejected. So that key should be used in a `<span title="the reason - appropriate key of the $tmp array - goes here">each id</span>` scenario to show the reason once the user hovers over each rejected id.

I can easily build a function to achieve what I want, but I'm sure there is an elegant, super short way to do it as well. It involves `array_walk_recursive()` but I can't get my mind around it yet, so I'm asking for your help guys!

Comment: What's about array_map function, you can create a new array from the resulting merge.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `array_diff` after using `array_merge` for checking elements were rejected

Comment: Sorry, this has nothing to do with what I'm trying to achieve!